# eth0 not added to bridge br0

Tags: networking, wifi, ethernet, raspbian-buster, bridge

I followed the [official guide](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point-bridged.md) and it works perfectly for an rPi3 running on buster but fails on an rPi4 running on buster-lite and I can't see why/I can't see the difference.

The problem: In contrast to the rPi3/buster the eth0 is not added to the bridge br0. eth0 receives an ip-address from the DHCP-server instead of the bridge br0. Somehow the `denyinterface` for eth0 in `dhcpcd.conf` is ignored. According to `journalctl -u dhcpcd` br0 aquires a weird ip-address.

```
... dhcpcd[712]: br0: probing for an IPv4LL address
... dhcpcd[712]: br0: using IPv4LL address 169.254.30.63
```

According to `dmesg` eth0 is not added to the bridge br0 on port 1. In contrast, on the rPi3 eth0 is added to the brigde on port 1 and wlan0 on port 2.

**Q** What am I missing?

*Note* On buster-lite I had to manually install dhcpcd5.

*Update 1* **rPi4**

```
$ cat /etc/os-release 
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)"

$ apt search dhcpcd
...
dhcpcd5/testing,now 1:8.1.2-1+rpt1 armhf [installed]
  DHCPv4, IPv6RA and DHCPv6 client with IPv4LL support
...
```

The **rPi3** had dhcpcd5 installed out of the box

```
$ cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)"

$ sudo apt search dhcpcd
...
dhcpcd5/testing,now 1:8.1.2-1+rpt1 armhf [installed]
DHCPv4, IPv6RA and DHCPv6 client with IPv4LL support
...
```

*Update 2* This hit me hard and unexpected: On top of raspbian-buster I installed [openmediavault (OMV)](https://www.openmediavault.org/).

The OMV installation injects

```
$ cat /run/systemd/network/10-netplan-eth0.network
[Match]
MACAddress=cc:aa:33:dd:00:bb

[Network]
DHCP=yes
LinkLocalAddressing=ipv6
IPv6AcceptRA=yes

[DHCP]
RouteMetric=100
UseMTU=true
```

and this file is breaking my bridge.

The rule-file is generated by `/etc/netplan/20-openmediavault-eth0.yaml`

**Q1** How can this be fixed properly?

Comment: The 192.164.x.x shows you have not got an IP address for that network interface.  Nothing 'weird' about it - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address

Comment: You may try to use systemd-networkd with [Setting up a Raspberry Pi as an access point - the easy way](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/88234/79866).

Comment: @Milliways To the point, I (re)installed dhcpcd5 because I couldn't find a `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Milliways pointed out, openmediavault (OMV) disables `dhcpcd`. Therefore, I doctored a netplan-yaml-file which I found on the net and it seems to do the trick:

```
$ cat 30-bridge.yaml 
network:
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      match:
        macaddress: dd:aa:33:dd:00:aa
      #accept-ra: true
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false

  bridges:
    br0:
      interfaces: [eth0]
      #addresses: [192.168.1.222/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.x.x
      mtu: 1500
      nameservers:
        addresses: [192.168.x.x]
      parameters:
        stp: true
        forward-delay: 4
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp6: true
      accept-ra: true
```

Any improvements to the netplan-yaml-file are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

First: calling it `dhcpcd5` may create confusion (esp for me :) because of the [history of dhcpcd](https://roy.marples.name/projects/dhcpcd/history.html). Yes - the executable file is named `dhcpcd5`, but it's generally referred to as `dhcpcd`. `man dhcpcd` is the same file as `man dhcpcd5`, and (as @Milliways pointed out in a comment) `dhcpcd` is a *link* to `dhcpcd5`. If you have `dhcpcd5` - you have `dhcpcd`. [Here's where I first learned of this.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/605831/there-are-two-dhcpcd-files-in-debian-buster-why-is-that)

Second: RPi OS Lite comes with `dhcpcd` (aka `dhcpcd5`) already installed - and even a `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` that works on almost all networks immediately and without editing.

If you don't have `dhcpcd` installed, then something odd may have happened to your system. You may have un-installed it with a `systemd-networkd` installation? If you didn't uninstall it (and that doesn't appear to be the case), then I'd suggest you start over - do a fresh install of `buster` lite on your SD card.

---

**EDIT**

You've edited your question, and it seems that you do have `dhcpcd`/`dhcpcd5` installed as it should be. Unless you've edited the default `/etc/dhcpcd-conf`, I think this is as it should be.

I've not tried the [procedure you referenced](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point-bridged.md), and I'm not in a position to try that now. The possibilities that present themselves immediately are 1) the procedure is flawed, 2) you've made a mis-step in executing it on the RPi4, or 3) there is a hardware or firmware diff between the RPi3 & RPi4 that is responsible.

I'll need to come back to this as I've run out of time for the present. The only other thought would be to look further into the possibility of a firmware-induced cause... for that, I'd post an "issue" (a question actually) to the [rpi-eeprom github repo](https://github.com/raspberrypi/rpi-eeprom).

Comment: @Milliways: Whoops!  :)   Thanks - I'll fix this shortly.

Answer (score 0):

**Q1 How can this be fixed properly?**

If you actually read the documentation for the software you installed (preferably BEFORE installing) it would have told you it uses `systemd-networkd` for networking.

The logs would have shown that OMV **DELETES** `dhcpcd`.

Then set networking to use `systemd-networkd` rather than a different system (`dhcpcd`)

Comment: Which log shows the deletion of dhcpcd?